# Threadpool Vs ProcessPool in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, threadpoolexecutor, process-pool

I was working in a code which performs lots of io operations like file downloading and graphs generations there may be 1000 plus files which will be the good method for this?

```
concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=10)
futures = [executorinsar.submit(locals()[configid + 6].ftptester, ch)]
```

i have used processpool executer and it seems working fine but i have seen some posts here which says threadpool executer is good for io bound operations  that  buu i have tries with

```
concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10)
futures = [executorinsar.submit(locals()[configid + 6].ftptester, ch)]
```

It works but it doesn't generates the graph fully some graphs are generated partially  is there any other good was to do it?